# Implementing Map Activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, mapactivity

I am trying to start a map activity by using intents on `onClick` but the app is crashing and gives this error. I want to launch into the map activity by button click. Can anyone give an idea how to integrate `MapActivity` in android project.

Logcat error logs are given below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gul.alviefinal.apk/com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:101)
            at com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:62)
            at com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 12:47:12.564  30396-30396/com.example.gul.alviefinal.apk E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-02 12:47:13.189  30396-30396/com.example.gul.alviefinal.apk E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ij.a
06-02 12:47:13.774  30396-30396/com.example.gul.alviefinal.apk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gul.alviefinal.apk/com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:101)
            at com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:62)
            at com.javaorigin.test.apk.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Any code? We cannot help you like this

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without seeing any code but my guess is that you haven't imported your libraries properly.

You can follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) from google on how to easily setup a map in your application by using a MapFragment, it's very straight forward and well written.